# Rendering a GSP from a Quartz job in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

I have a quartz job that needs to render a GSP, when I tried:

```
def g = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib()
def text = g.render(template: "/templates/myTemplate",
          model: [language: language,
                  product: product])
```

I received the following exception:

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request. [See nested exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsTaskClassJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:81)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder$currentRequestAttributes.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.plugins.support.WebMetaUtils$_registerMethodMissingForTags_closure23.doCall(WebMetaUtils.groovy:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaObjectProtocol$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure26.doCall(GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin.groovy:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:813)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1060)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
```

Using Grails 1.3.2. Any ideas on what I can do to get this working? 
EDIT: It's a current limitation with Grails http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround could be to use [template-engine](http://www.grails.org/plugin/grails-template-engine) plugin.

Comment: Thank you! This worked well for me, I was going to add the mocking of the request context to get templating working in my app, but it's great that there's a plugin I can already use. Just watch out, I had to hack it a bit to get around this issue: GrailsTemplateEngineService line 45 controllerName should be pluginName

Answer (score 5):

Since Grails 2.0.4 you can use

```
grails.gsp.PageRenderer.render
```

to render templates outside of the request context.

Comment: This page has a good example of using PageRender.render here http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html